# Refresh Expression after script task

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

**Bumping due to no suggestions**

I have an SSIS package with a declared variable - `claimMaxDate`. The first step in my package is to populate the variable with the `MAX(TIME_STAMP)` from a SQL Server table.
I want to use that date to run a different query but it ***must*** use the ODBC data source in SSIS.
Since parameters can't be passed to the ODBC data source, I'm trying to use expressions.

This is what I've added to the data flow task:

[image]

However, the expression never refreshes with the date that is populated in the variable. I've debugged and confirmed that the variable is being populated. Variable property `EvaluateAsExpression` is also true.

Am I missing a step here?

[image]

Comment: can you show add snapshot of the package control flow?

Comment: Check that you dont have the variable duplicated with different scope. Or it's scope isn't global. To view non global variable click on each component and check the variables window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else come across this question. The answer was simple. The expression was evaluating at run time, it just doesn't show the update when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather change your package design. Create a *string* variable like **SQL_DFT_Select** which evaluates with your expression. Then specify this variable as a query source at **ODBC data source**. By doing this you can set a breakpoint at your **Data Flow Task** step and check this variable.
On your original question -- it can be the case that your expression is evaluated at validation time, then your *claimMaxTime* variable is empty. Later change of this variable does not trigger update of property expression. However, every reading of a variable with an expression re-evaluates this expression; that is why I recommended switching to query from variable design.